# How to get Facebook Page info using Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm sure I'm missing something but, currently, I don't understand what.

I'm playing with Guzzle, and I'm trying to get a page info:

```
<?php

/**
 * Example of usage of APIConnect to get information
 * about a Facebook Page through Graph API.
 */

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

/** SET HERE A PAGE */
$page = 'SamplePage';

$remoteUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get($remoteUrl);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// "200"
echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// {"type":"User"...'
```

This is the code that the Guzzle documentation shows.

Now, I'm expecting that calling this code, returns some objects that contains, in one of their properties, the following JSON response, as it is the one I receive if I call the URL directly in the browser:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

**Why, instead, if I use the Guzzle methods to get Response values I see it is `null`? What Am I missing?**

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I solved this.

The first problem was that I used an old version of Guzzle.

In my composer.json I had this:

```
## THIS IS WRONG ##
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "*@stable"
},
```

But in this way I downloaded Guzzle 3, that is an old version.

[To download the new version (the 6)](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/overview.html), I changed the line in this way:

```
## THIS IS CORRECT ##
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6"
},
```

So, I have now Guzzle 6.

Also the code has to be changed. This is the correct version:

```
<?php

/**
 * Example of usage of APIConnect to get information
 * about a Facebook Page through Graph API.
 */

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/SamplePage'; // Set the URL
$api_end_point = '';
$end_point = '';

$client = new Client(
    ['base_uri' => $url]
    );

$path = $api_end_point . $end_point;
echo $path;

try
{
    $res = $client->get($path);
}
catch (RequestException $e)
{
    $res = $e->getRequest();

    if ($e->hasResponse())
    {
        $res = $e->getResponse();
    }
}

echo $res->getStatusCode();
// "400"
print_r($res->getHeader('content-type'));
// Array ( [0] => text/javascript; charset=UTF-8 )
echo $res->getBody();
// {"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

Now Guzzle returns the response. It is a 400 Status Code because we need authentication, but this is another question :)